# How to find the limit of an algebraic function

Tags: limits

The question is to find this limit:
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^\frac{5}{3}- x ^\frac{1}{3}+7}{x^\frac{8}{5} +3x + \sqrt{x}}$$
I need any hint to help since I tried so much and couldn't solve it.

Comment: This, as it looks, is not a rational function.

Comment: What is it called?

Comment: Look at dominant coefficients of the numerator and denominator (those with highest degree), and factor them out, leaving $x$ to negative powers. Then, what you have factored out gives you the limit.

Comment: @user689 : I'm pretty sure the label "algebraic function" applies.  Or you could just call it a "function".  A rational function is the quotient of two polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x$ tends to infinity, the dominant term of polynomial is the one with the largest power. Hence
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^\frac{5}{3}- x ^\frac{1}{3}+7}{x^\frac{8}{5} +3x + \sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^\frac53}{x^\frac85}\to\infty$$

Comment: I know this is only applicable to polynomials(i.e that contains only exponents belonging to the natural number set) right?

Comment: For $x>0$, this applies to all reals

Comment: Ok thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Divide both numerator and denominator with $x^{\alpha}$ where $$\alpha = \max \{\frac{5}{3}, \frac{1}{3},\frac{5}{8}, 1, \frac{1}{2}\}$$

and then take the limit

Comment: This way  really works for all functions of this type. +1

Answer (score 1):

since $\frac{5}{3}\gt\frac{8}{5}$, then the term with the largest degree is in the numerator.  Thus your limit will tend toward $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^\frac{5}{3}- x ^\frac{1}{3}+7}{x^\frac{8}{5} +3x + \sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^\frac53}{x^\frac85}\to\infty$. If you want to do it in more steps divde the numerator and the denomerator by $x^{\frac{5}{3}}$, after this and taking the limit will show that the above equation is true.